# Is it possible to embed MS Word Editor in web Browser Control

Tags: c#, ms-word, activexobject

I wonder is it possible to embed word editor as a control within Web Browser Control to write text etc and then can retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

We have telerik rad editor which can be embedded into HTML page. You can perform text formatting in the same manner that you do in MS Word. You can even retrieve the text that you have entered into rad editor

Comment: Thing is that client is too much used to of Word that they need it in Desktop App.